# Convert bump node back into its input texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

Let's say I have a Bump node with a greyscale texture going into its Height input. The node outputs a Normal socket, which you then usually plug into your shader node.

Is there any conversion I can do to the vector coming out of the Bump Nodes normal socket that would give me the input texture again?

Comment: could you explain your case? in what case would it be useful?

Comment: I don't have a specific case, I'm just curious. I suppose it could come up in cases where the bump has been baked to a texture.